# Clamped Increment Integer?

Tags: c++, boost

Does the standard (or boost) provide a method for incrementing an integer ensuring that it doesn't carry over and start back at zero but keeps the value at max? Or would I simply have to create my own (this really does seem like a little utility function that should be included).

```
template<typename T>
void Increment(T& x)
{
    if(x != std::numeric_limits<T>::max()) ++x;
}
```

Comment: That would be a saturating increment. A safe increment would indicate somehow that the result overflowed.

Comment: As far as I know, there's nothing like that in the C++ standard or in boost.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121240/saturating-addition-in-c

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there is no such utility, so you would need to build you own.

There is a good article that covers saturating arithmetic: [Branchfree Saturating Arithmetic](http://locklessinc.com/articles/sat_arithmetic/) and they cover all the arithmetic operations. Their examples are in C but should not be difficult to translate.

For your case we would be looking at addition. They assume the following:

```
#include <limits.h>

typedef unsigned u32b;

typedef signed s32b;
```

and for unsigned addition they provide the following code:

```
u32b sat_addu32b(u32b x, u32b y)
{
    u32b res = x + y;
    res |= -(res < x);

    return res;
}
```

and for signed addition:

```
s32b sat_adds32b(s32b x, s32b y)
{
    u32b ux = x;
    u32b uy = y;
    u32b res = ux + uy;

    /* Calculate overflowed result. (Don't change the sign bit of ux) */
    ux = (ux >> 31) + INT_MAX;

    /* Force compiler to use cmovns instruction */
    if ((s32b) ((ux ^ uy) | ~(uy ^ res)) >= 0)
    {
        res = ux;
    }

    return res;
}
```

As Pascal Cuoq notes in a comment the unsigned case assumes twos complement which should be fine for the vast majority of the cases but the standard does not make assumptions on the underlying representation.

Comment: Do you mean the signed case assumes two's-complement?  The unsigned case assumes modular arithmetic, which the Standard mandates for unsigned int, though not necessarily for smaller unsigned types (addition is generally safe even for those, but in a nasty implementation even incrementing an unsigned short could yield Undefined Behavior even if it has the same range as unsigned int.

Comment: @supercat you know I am not sure, it looks like he is assuming promotion to a signed type but it does not seem like this should be the case.

Comment: Subtracting a larger unsigned value from a smaller one yields (UINT_MAX+1) minus the difference.