# Managing casts from uint64_t to uint32_t

Tags: c++, tcp

Working on a TCP implementation and have encountered the need to cast from a `uint64_t` to a wrapping `uint32_t`, but am really not sure how to account for possible overflows.

[image: This image describes the data types.] `absolute seqno` is the `uint64_t` and goes up to 2^64 - 1(max possible length) while `seqno` goes up to 2^32 - 1 and then goes back to 0. `SYN` is a `uint32_t` representing the starting of `seqno`.

I'm unsure as to how accounting for overflows must be done; my current conversion implementation is as follows:

```
uint32_t wrap(uint64_t n, uint32_t syn) {

    if (n < std::pow(2, 32) - syn) {
        return static_cast<uint32_t>(n) + syn;
    }

    return syn;
}
```

Is there a better, proper way to do this conversion to ensure resetting of `seqno` regardless of the value of `absolute seqno` ? Thanks.

LE for clarity: converting 260 to `unsigned char` should give me 4(when exceeding 255, the "counting" starts again from 0).

Comment: Unclear what you want to do tbh. Does this help: [Saturating subtract/add for unsigned bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33481295/10147399)

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili have added an edit with an example. Same logic, but for possible very large numbers that would overflow multiple times.

Comment: Don't use `std::pow` for integers. It's a floating point function. If you want `2^32 - syn` you'd be better off with `(1ul << 32 - syn)` or since signed over/underflow is welldefined, `std::uint32_t(0) - syn` (since 2^32 in an unsigned 32 bit integer will overflow to 0)