# Why does gcc reorder the local variable in function?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly, disassembly

I wrote a C program that just read/write a large array. I compiled the program with command `gcc -O0 program.c -o program`  Out of curiosity, I dissemble the C program with `objdump -S` command.

The code and assembly of the `read_array` and `write_array` functions are attached at the end of this question.

I'm trying to interpret how gcc compiles the function. I used `//` to add my comments and questions

Take one piece of the beginning of the assembly code of the `write_array()` function

```
  4008c1:   48 89 7d e8             mov    %rdi,-0x18(%rbp) // this is the first parameter of the fuction
  4008c5:   48 89 75 e0             mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp) // this is the second parameter of the fuction
  4008c9:   c6 45 ff 01             movb   $0x1,-0x1(%rbp) // comparing with the source code, I think this is the `char tmp` variable 
  4008cd:   c7 45 f8 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp) // this should be the `int i` variable.
```

**What I don't understand is:**

1) `char tmp` is obviously defined *after* `int i` in `write_array` function. Why gcc reorder the memory location of these two local variables?

2) From the offset, `int i` is at `-0x8(%rbp)` and `char tmp` is at `-0x1(%rbp)`, which indicates variable `int i` takes *7* bytes? This is quite weird because `int i` should be 4 bytes on x86-64 machine. Isn't it? My speculation is that gcc tries to do some alignment?

3) I found the gcc optimization choices are quite *interesting*. Is there some good documents/book that explain how *gcc* works? (The third question may be off-topic, and if you think so, please just ignore. I just try to see if there is some short cut to learn the underlying mechanisms gcc uses for compilation. :-) )

**Below is the piece of function code:**

```
#define CACHE_LINE_SIZE 64
static inline void
read_array(char* array, long size)
{
    int i;
    char tmp;
    for ( i = 0; i < size; i+= CACHE_LINE_SIZE )
    {
        tmp = array[i];
    }
    return;
}

static inline void
write_array(char* array, long size)
{
    int i;
    char tmp = 1;
    for ( i = 0; i < size; i+= CACHE_LINE_SIZE )
    {
        array[i] = tmp;
    }
    return;
}
```

**Below is the piece of disassembled code for `write_array`, from gcc -O0:**

```
00000000004008bd <write_array>:
  4008bd:   55                      push   %rbp
  4008be:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4008c1:   48 89 7d e8             mov    %rdi,-0x18(%rbp)
  4008c5:   48 89 75 e0             mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
  4008c9:   c6 45 ff 01             movb   $0x1,-0x1(%rbp)
  4008cd:   c7 45 f8 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
  4008d4:   eb 13                   jmp    4008e9 <write_array+0x2c>
  4008d6:   8b 45 f8                mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
  4008d9:   48 98                   cltq
  4008db:   48 03 45 e8             add    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
  4008df:   0f b6 55 ff             movzbl -0x1(%rbp),%edx
  4008e3:   88 10                   mov    %dl,(%rax)
  4008e5:   83 45 f8 40             addl   $0x40,-0x8(%rbp)
  4008e9:   8b 45 f8                mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
  4008ec:   48 98                   cltq
  4008ee:   48 3b 45 e0             cmp    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
  4008f2:   7c e2                   jl     4008d6 <write_array+0x19>
  4008f4:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  4008f5:   c3                      retq
```

Comment: The `int` must be 4-byte aligned and it can't be at `-0x4` as that would cause it to overlap with the char.

Comment: Important point: I don't believe gcc *would* reorder the arguments unless the caller and callee were both in the same compilation unit (as they seem to be here).

Comment: Decisions made at levels below `-O3` don't really matter

Comment: @M.M If the `int` was at `-0x4` then the `char` would be somewhere else, duh.

Comment: If `int` was at `-0x4`, it is assigned by 4 bytes; and then we can put `char` to `-0x5`, can't we? Isn't it more space saving?

Comment: OK. I agree people usually compile with `-O3`. However, since the levels below `-O3` does exist, I think their existence  has a reason. That's why I hope to understand why gcc made the "reordering" decision. :-)

Comment: `-O0` is only really useful if you are debugging (there is usually a much clearer association between _C_ code and the underlying assembly). In the old days debugging optimized code was more difficult, but with modern GCC and GDB that really isn't an issue. In the very early days of some compilers there were bugs with the optimizers so falling back to no optimization was a hack to avoid issues. `-O0` is also valuable if you are trying to understand standard calling conventions. When releasing software I can't think of a reason to use `-O0` (no optimizations). `-O2` is the minimum I use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even at `-O0`, gcc doesn't emit definitions for `static inline` functios unless there's a caller.  In that case, it doesn't actually inline: instead it emits a stand-alone definition.  So I guess your disassembly is from that.

---

Are you using a really old gcc version?  gcc 4.6.4 puts the vars in that order on the stack, but 4.7.3 and later use the other order:

```
    movb    $1, -5(%rbp)    #, tmp
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)    #, i
```

In your asm, they're stored in order of initialization rather than declaration, but I think that's just by chance, since the order changed with gcc 4.7.  Also, tacking on an initializers like `int i=1;` doesn't change the allocation order, so that completely torpedoes that theory.

Remember that [gcc is designed around a series of transformations from source to asm, so `-O0` doesn't mean "no optimization"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33284629/224132).  You should think of `-O0` as leaving out some things that `-O3` normally does.  There is no option that tries to make a literal-as-possible translation from source to asm.

Once gcc does decide which order to allocate space for them:

- the `char` at `rbp-1`: That's the first available location that can hold a `char`.  If there was another `char` that needed storing, it could go at `rbp-2`.
- the `int` at `rbp-8`: Since the 4 bytes from `rbp-1` to `rbp-4` isn't free, the next available naturally-aligned location is `rbp-8`.

Or with gcc 4.7 and newer, -4 is the first available spot for an int, and -5 is the next byte below that.

---

#### RE: space saving:

It's true that putting the char at -5 makes the lowest touched address `%rsp-5`, instead of `%rsp-8`, but this doesn't save anything.

The stack pointer is 16B-aligned in the AMD64 SysV ABI.  (Technically, `%rsp+8` (the start of stack args) is aligned on function entry, before you push anything.)  The only way for `%rbp-8` to touch a new page or cache-line that `%rbp-5` wouldn't is for the stack to be less than 4B-aligned.  This is extremely unlikely, even in 32bit code.

As far as how much stack is "allocated" or "owned" by the function: In the AMD64 SysV ABI, the function "owns" the red zone of 128B below `%rsp` [(That size was chosen because a one-byte displacement can go up to `-128`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35619528/224132).  Signal handlers and any other asynchronous users of the user-space stack will avoid clobbering the red zone, which is why the function can write to memory below `%rsp` without decrementing `%rsp`.  So from that perspective, it doesn't matter how much of the red-zone we use; the chances of a signal handler running out of stack is unaffected.

In 32bit code, where there's no redzone, for either order gcc reserves space on the stack with `sub $16, %esp`.  (try with `-m32` on godbolt).  So again, it doesn't matter whether we use 5 or 8 bytes, because we reserve in units of 16.

When there are many `char` and `int` variables, gcc packs the `char`s into 4B groups, instead of losing space to fragmentation, even when the declarations are mixed together:

```
void many_vars(void) {
  char tmp = 1;  int i=1;
  char t2 = 2;   int i2 = 2;
  char t3 = 3;   int i3 = 3;
  char t4 = 4;
}
```

[with gcc 4.6.4 `-O0 -fverbose-asm`](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g464,options:%27-xc++-std%3Dgnu99+-fverbose-asm+-O0+-march%3Dnative%27,source:%27void+many_vars(void)+%7B%0A++char+tmp+%3D+1%3B%0A++int+i%3D1%3B%0A++char+t2+%3D+2%3B%0A++int+i2+%3D+2%3B%0A++char+t3+%3D+3%3B%0A++int+i3+%3D+3%3B%0A++char+t4+%3D+4%3B%0A%7D%0A%27)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3), which helpfully labels which store is for which variable, which is why compiler asm output is preferable to disassembly:

```
    pushq   %rbp  #
    movq    %rsp, %rbp      #,
    movb    $1, -4(%rbp)    #, tmp
    movl    $1, -16(%rbp)   #, i
    movb    $2, -3(%rbp)    #, t2
    movl    $2, -12(%rbp)   #, i2
    movb    $3, -2(%rbp)    #, t3
    movl    $3, -8(%rbp)    #, i3
    movb    $4, -1(%rbp)    #, t4
    popq    %rbp    #
    ret
```

I think variables go in either forward or reverse order of declaration, depending on gcc version, at `-O0`.

---

#### I made a version of your `read_array` function that works with optimization on:

```
// assumes that size is non-zero.  Use a while() instead of do{}while() if you want extra code to check for that case.
void read_array_good(const char* array, size_t size) {
    const volatile char *vp = array;
    do {
      (void) *vp;    // this counts as accessing the volatile memory, with gcc/clang at least
      vp += CACHE_LINE_SIZE/sizeof(vp[0]);
    } while (vp < array+size);
}
```

[Compiles to the following, with gcc 5.3 -O3 -march=haswell](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:%27-xc+-Wall+-Wextra+-std%3Dgnu99+-fverbose-asm+-O3+-march%3Dhaswell%27,sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4DOAXOiBmA6ACwD4AoE4XcZAYQEFqAJAUQH0AZASQDlWBlDgFpMkANgAsSJAHopSAGIcAGgFkmALiQw0yNAE80EAPZgcSQwCck1AAoBVDgBEkGQ0gC2AQwDWyDARBoSDgwGDDmCAC0AA7mhoamHmBwSFEWGB4ARlAI5JRgNGy8Alb0zOzcfIJMZDKYHhggEEjgUFRIJABuhiDJAO7mIBgILB7m5h66ABQQBKMAVEij47oANEhQxgDmSGggAF4IAJRIAN4kkpLgGM0A3OcXM6POblFIALxIAIx3F0EWSJNmu8kAAGG5AlA7fYIcEgADUHzojFYnB4LH4QiQxyWEwA2iAALrAjAvO4AXxqUjqDSaLSonW6yXCHjgIzGExYGViPjA01m5gWONW6y2UIOxzOvyut1%2BkhkzTA1w2hleRhgioQll6Fi8gVSFiguiQvUGBBFYG2uwOeEkAHV/DMdgRDDAoMkMjpoSxroldL0JmsPFA/C7NmajC8QNlzIFRggwAByH1QDa9BDJFyLNBoGBuZBgVyGDqanCpv6WdW7Tb5DMEZD%2Bo1%2BBBGiCJctQ6vpvD3SSPSwkqI/C7yvwBZqBOC5jKLJJmKINNzQ2MN5yuAuji3d344f6AkDAsEQsUw5oIkrI8pojHCY4D4FC/EE8mUrM5vOBPz1Y/jpAFsARA5YgZHokGZVkhRYTY4jgaZjEwJA%2B0FdlhStYZrlQiUewQuDri6KB6ijZA%2ByQOYOleD4hSHSQ4FcSVZUmLoemOUjBywyQyKQM8kTKVFKiEKloXiBiolxEECUOKikDJY1/GyAEOMhIU4Qw58yEpGQNM0rTZCQAAVAYgyQYsYxAOC1jQQw8zMUwmzcX9DGuBBizAbCxgQCAMDIRimQQFk2WWFgOjEWCwHgxDFmQ8yvXQ6FMN%2BIxQtwwx8IaOTpRY4EQvgq45kOSisNQ71rLLD4wSw%2BIywiRFCgESSaNONj5MZZiyMk9jXi40oUQqdEqgEg4hLI0TxLa78qvPHieuvSTpN6WSEEBVDUA%2BCrDF6LFVOAny/IgjoAGYsuucKhSig4iowhr4pwozkoIuTiIyijkMkubCIBJaiGqoo4tlJbxuoGrRoY5qSNaxqOM6i9eN6/jUMGkSxIkrCKQpLzGVA3zwOQwLPkOhD%2BSQ5ZTrQ48ft7a68Lu5B0o4j48ZyvLnqwrDXrkyYPsRLrLz4pgyYuYGmNB1jZSMjrOahqa%2BrhnBhOGpGRb%2B8XJqvKoZpIVGSHlTYICaTwfFjY0EBAcxkmVV4TT8TRQpATtkiWxJTbiVUXQ1Sw1CkLaMZ27GoMMVkOgAJjx47IuPc7Ysuh4Kdu1KiP5IX7yZ7dd0K6591K2FUGPWFIeVnmsUagW4GOIbCWfIAAAA%3D%3D)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3):

```
        addq    %rdi, %rsi      # array, D.2434
.L11:
        movzbl  (%rdi), %eax        # MEM[(const char *)array_1], D.2433
        addq    $64, %rdi       #, array
        cmpq    %rsi, %rdi      # D.2434, array
        jb      .L11        #,
        ret
```

Casting an expression to void is the canonical way to tell the compiler that a value is used.  e.g. to suppress unused-variable warnings, you can write `(void)my_unused_var;`.

For gcc and clang, doing that with a `volatile` pointer dereference does generate a memory access, with no need for a tmp variable.  The C standard is very non-specific about what constitutes access to something that's `volatile`, so this probably isn't perfectly portable.  Another way is to `xor` the values you read into an accumulator, and then store that to a global.  As long as you don't use whole-program optimization, the compiler doesn't know that nothing reads the global, so it can't optimize away the calculation.

See [the `vmtouch` source code](https://hoytech.com/vmtouch/) for an example of this second technique.  (It actually uses a global variable for the accumulator, which makes clunky code.  Of course, that hardly matters since it's touching pages, not just cache lines, so it very quickly bottlenecks on TLB misses and page faults, even with a memory read-modify-write in the loop-carried  dependency chain.)

---

I tried and failed to write something that gcc or clang would compile to a function with no prologue (which assumes that `size` is initially non-zero).  GCC always wants to `add rsi,rdi` for a `cmp/jcc` loop condition, even with `-march=haswell` where `sub rsi,64`/`jae` can macro-fuse just as well as `cmp/jcc`.  But in general on AMD, what GCC has fewer uops inside the loop.

```
read_array_handtuned_haswell:
.L0
    movzx   eax, byte [rdi]     ; overwrite the full RAX to avoid any partial-register false deps from writing AL
    add     rdi, 64
    sub     rsi, 64
    jae     .L0           ; or ja, depending on what semantics you want
    ret
```

**[Godbolt Compiler Explorer link with all my attempts and trial versions](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:%27-xc+-Wall+-Wextra+-std%3Dgnu99+-fverbose-asm+-O3+-march%3Dhaswell%27,sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4DOAXOiBmA6ACwD4AoE4XcZAYQEFqAJAUQH0AZASQDlWBlDgFpMkANgAsSJAHopSAGIcAGgFkmALiQw0yNAE80EAPZgcSQwCck1AAoBVDgBEkGQ0gC2AQwDWyDARBoSDgwGDDmCAC0AA7mhoamHmBwSFEWGB4ARlAI5JRgNGy8Alb0zOzcfIJMZDKYHhggEEjgUFRIJABuhiDJAO7mIBgILB7m5h66ABQQBKMAVEij47oANEhQxgDmSGggAF4IAJRIAN4kkpLgGM0A3OcXM6POblFIALxIAIx3F0EWSJNmu8kAAGG5AlA7fYIcEgADUHzojFYnB4LH4QiQxyWEwA2iAALrAjAvO4AXxqUjqDSaLSonW6yXCHjgIzGExYGViPjA01m5gWONW6y2UIOxzOvyut1%2BkhkzTA1w2hleRhgioQll6Fi8gVSFiguiQvUGBBFYG2uwOeEkAHV/DMdgRDDAoMkMjpoSxroldL0JmsPFA/C7NmajC8QNlzIFRggwAByH1QDa9BDJFyLNBoGBuZBgVyGDqanCpv6WdW7Tb5DMEZD%2Bo1%2BBBGiCJctQ6vpvD3SSPSwkqI/C7yvwBZqBOC5jKLJJmKINNzQ2MN5yuAuji3d344f6AkDAsEQsUw5oIkrI8pojHCY4D4FC/EE8mUrM5vOBPz1Y/jpAFsARA5YgZHokGZVkhRYTY4jgaZjEwJA%2B0FdlhStYZrlQiUewQuDri6KB6ijZA%2ByQOYOleD4hSHSQ4FcSVZUmLoemOUjBywyQyKQM8kTKVFKiEKloXiBiolxEECUOKikDJY1/GyAEOMhIU4Qw58yEpGQNM0rTZCQAAVAYgyQYsYxAOC1jQQw8zMUwmzcX9DGuBBizAbCxgQCAMDIRimQQFk2WWFgOjEWCwHgxDFmQ8yvXQ6FMN%2BIxQtwwx8IaOTpRY4EQvgq45kOSisNQ71rLLD4wSw%2BIywiRFCgESSaNONj5MZZiyMk9jXi40oUQqdEqgEg4hLI0TxLa78qvPHieuvSTpN6WSEEBVDUA%2BCrDF6LFVOAny/IgjoAGYsuucKhSig4iowhr4pwozkoIuTiIyijkMkubCIBJaiGqoo4tlJbxuoGrRoY5qSNaxqOM6i9eN6/jUMGkSxIkrCKQpLzGVA3zwOQwLPkOhD%2BSQ5ZTrQ48ft7a68Lu5B0o4j48ZyvLnqwrDXrkyYPsRLrLz4pgyYuYGmNB1jZSMjrOahqa%2BrhnBhOGpGRb%2B8XJqvKoZpIVGSHlTYICaTwfFjY0EBAcxkmVV4TT8TRQpATtkiWxJTbiVUXQ1Sw1CkLaMZ27GoMMVkOgAJjx47IuPc7Ysuh4Kdu1KiP5IX7yZ7dd0K6591K2FUGPWFIeVnmsUagW4GOIbCWfIAAAA%3D%3D)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)**

I can get similar if the loop-termination condition is `je`, in a loop like `do { ... } while( size -= CL_SIZE );`  But I can't seem to convince gcc to catch unsigned borrow when subtracting.  It want to subtract and then `cmp -64/jb` to detect underflow.  It's [not that hard to get compilers to check the carry flag after an add to detect carry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121240/saturating-addition-in-c) :/

It's also easy to get compilers to make a 4-insn loop, but not without prologue.  e.g. calculate an end pointer (array+size) and increment a pointer until it's greater or equal.

Fortunately this is not a big deal; the loop we do get is good.

Comment: I'd venture to guess that _static inline_ wouldn't emit code if there wasn't a function(s) in the object that actually used both the read_array and write_array. Maybe the OP left that off the question for brevity? Hard to tell, but I figure the code shown was not complete.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Good point.  I tested, and adding a `void foo(char *p, long s) { write_array(p,s); read_array_broken(p,s); }` to the compilation unit does get stand-alone definitions emitted for the `static inline` functions.

Answer (score -2):

For local variable saved in stack, the address order depends in the stack grow direction. you can refer to [Does stack grow upward or downward?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677415/does-stack-grow-upward-or-downward) for more information.

> This is quite weird because int i should be 4 bytes on x86-64 machine. Isn't it?

If my memory serve me correctly, the size of int on x86-64 machine is 8. you can confirm it by writing a test application to print `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: The size of an `int` is implementation defined. When compiling for 64-bit code on Linux, GCC uses 32-bit `int`, `long` and `long long` are both 64-bit.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models has a breakdown of some of the more common 64-bit data models.

Comment: most (if not all) modern 64-bit architectures have 32-bit int https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models

Comment: Local variables on the stack don't have to depend on whether the stack grows up or down. With no optimizations, it may well be related to the order in which the compiler traverses the data structures that represent the source code internally (like Abstract Syntax Trees etc). You can't rely on the order of individual variables on the stack. If you want to maintain order of variables you'd have to place them in a `struct` (or other similar mechanism)

Comment: Well, if you're using x86-64 the real issue is not that an int is 8 bytes, it's that the stack is 8 bytes "wide." The smallest thing allocated on it will be 8 bytes.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer : When passing parameters with typical calling conventions, parameters are 8 bytes wide. Allocating space for local variables on the stack can see the data packed by default to their natural alignment. the total size of that allocated space will generally be a multiple of 8. If I had 7 `char` variables for local variables I'd rather see them take 8 bytes total (including padding) rather than 7 * 8 = 56 bytes (8 bytes for each character).

Comment: Ah, yes, true enough Michael. I was thinking of different data types.

Comment: gcc 4.6 and earlier use the OP's ordering, gcc 4.7 and later use the other order.  @MichaelPetch is correct: it's all just gcc internals because it doesn't matter for anything:  Code that assumes anything about the relative addresses of local variables is badly broken.  I posted an answer with this and some other interesting stuff (like a non-broken version of `read_array`.)