# Why is the variable allocated the same way in both programs?

Tags: c, memory, gdb, allocation, buffer-overflow

I have following code to showcase stack-based buffer overflow.

```
int check_authentication(char *password) {
  int auth_flag = 0;
  char password_buffer[16];

  strcpy(password_buffer, password);
  if(strcmp(password_buffer, "Admin") == 0)
    auth_flag = 1;
  return auth_flag;
}
```

Here when user inputs any string with length greater than 16 will allow access. To show other case of not overflow the `auth_flag` I have the following code:

```
int check_authentication(char *password) {
  char password_buffer[16];
  int auth_flag = 0;

  strcpy(password_buffer, password);
  if(strcmp(password_buffer, "Admin") == 0)
    auth_flag = 1;
  return auth_flag;
}
```

As the stack works as LIFO, `auth_flag` should have a lower address than `password_buffer` in the second example. GDB with break point at `strcpy` looks as follows:

```
(gdb) x/16xw password_buffer
0x61fefc:       0x696d6441      0x7659006e      0xc9da078f      0xfffffffe
0x61ff0c:       0x00000001      0x76596cad      0x00401990      0x0061ff38
0x61ff1c:       0x00401497      0x00ae1658      0x00000000      0x0028f000
0x61ff2c:       0x00400080      0x0061ff1c      0x0028f000      0x0061ff94
(gdb) x/x &auth_flag
0x61ff0c:       0x00000001
```

I expected the `password_buffer` to start from `0x61ff10`, right after `auth_flag`. Where I am wrong?

I am using gcc (gcc version 9.2.0 (MinGW.org GCC Build-20200227-1) and gdb (GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1) on windows 10 with no modification to SEHOP or ASLR.

Comment: I don't know the specifics of how GCC maps local variables to stack locations, but the LIFO behavior that you refer to typically refers to pushing and popping, and that's not how local variables are stored. There, the compiler typically calculates a single block of memory to be reserved on entry. Most compilers that I know intimately allocate locals in the order they are declared, from higher to lower addresses on stack, but I don't think that is specified one way or the other in the standard for `c`.

Comment: You probably mean "allocated" not "assigned". You need to be aware that local variables are not pushed on the stack separately or in a given order. Instead the required amount of memory is simply allocated on the stack on function entry. It's up to the compiler how to order the variables within that memory area.

Comment: If you want to guarantee that one thing follows another physically in memory, put them both in the same containing structure.  If they are independently declared in a function, then they could be allocated in any physical order, and other things could appear between them.  In fact, if the compiler optimizes your code, then `auth_flag` will probably be kept in a register and won't even have a memory address.  The same could even happen for a structure member.

Comment: I would be indeed surprised if `auth_flag` existed on the stack. Depending on the architecture/calling convention, it will likely just place the result in the `eax`/`r0` register or something like that. As you can [see here](https://godbolt.org/z/hQSpwE), removing the flag from the source code generates the same instructions.

Comment: Related: [Why does gcc reorder the local variable in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36298567/why-does-gcc-reorder-the-local-variable-in-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, local variables are not pushed onto and popped from the stack. Instead, when the function call is executed, the runtime allocates some space on the stack for the local variables. It is called [Function Prologue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue) and has a known sequence (in many cases - see the comment)

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, N
```

where `N` is the space reserved for the local variables.

For some reason, GCC always allocates the memory location `[rbp-4]` for `auth_flag` local variable and that's why you do not see any difference (check [this](https://godbolt.org/z/E55TUm) vs [this](https://godbolt.org/z/VVL3rl)). Could be how the compiler is designed...

On the other hand, clang does what you expect the compiler to do, at least when allocating the place on the stack for your `auth_flag` local variable. No optimisations are used for the compiler

```
check_authentication:                   # @check_authentication
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 48
        lea     rax, [rbp - 32]
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 8], rdi
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 12], 0
        mov     rsi, qword ptr [rbp - 8]
        mov     rdi, rax
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 40], rax # 8-byte Spill
        call    strcpy
        mov     esi, offset .L.str
        mov     rdi, qword ptr [rbp - 40] # 8-byte Reload
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 48], rax # 8-byte Spill
        call    strcmp
        cmp     eax, 0
        jne     .LBB0_2
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 12], 1
.LBB0_2:
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rbp - 12]
        add     rsp, 48
        pop     rbp
        ret
.L.str:
        .asciz  "Admin"
```

compare the above with the below code where `password_buffer` is declared before the `auth_flag` local variable.

```
check_authentication:                   # @check_authentication
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 64
        lea     rax, [rbp - 32]
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 8], rdi
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 36], 0
        mov     rsi, qword ptr [rbp - 8]
        mov     rdi, rax
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 48], rax # 8-byte Spill
        call    strcpy
        mov     esi, offset .L.str
        mov     rdi, qword ptr [rbp - 48] # 8-byte Reload
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 56], rax # 8-byte Spill
        call    strcmp
        cmp     eax, 0
        jne     .LBB0_2
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 36], 1
.LBB0_2:
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rbp - 36]
        add     rsp, 64
        pop     rbp
        ret
.L.str:
        .asciz  "Admin"
```

The `mov     dword ptr [rbp - XXX], 0` line in above code snippets are where your local `auth_flag` variable is declared and initialised. As you can see, the reserved location on the stack for the local variable changes based on your buffer size. It is worth compiling your code with clang and debugging it with lldb I think.

Comment: "has a known sequence"  is incorrect. The sequence you "know" will only be emitted by some compilers, only on some platforms, and only with optimization off.

Comment: Thanks. Just added a note to the statement